# TeXstudio: How to add shortcut for "Go to PDF"

Tags: texstudio

I'd like to know how to add a key shortcut for "Go to PDF" in TexStudio. I can not find it in  `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio`->`Shortcuts`.

**Edit:** This question is completely different from the suggested question because it asks for how to set a key shortcut for "Go to PDF", not how to perform it.

Comment: In my TeXstudio (Linux) the F7 key opens the PDF file created in the compilation of the TeX file.

Comment: It turns out what is called "Go to PDF" on a right click in the editor (or Ctrl-click) is equivalent to pressing F7 (View) when the pdf is --already open-- and the focus is in the editor. It appears under the name "View" in the menu and in the shortcut editor, instead of "Go to PDF", which is why it is hard to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcuts used by TeXStudio are customizable:
`Options` -> `Configure TeXStudio` -> `Shortcuts`:

- To change the shortcut to view the PDF:
  `Menus` -> `Tools` -> `View` then change `F7` in third column (`Current Shortcut`).
- To change the shortcut for `Go to source`: `Menus PDF-Viewer` -> `Window` -> `Show` -> `Go to source` then change `Ctrl+'` in third column (`Current Shortcut`)

Comment: "Go to Source" by shortcut key seems not as accurate as click directly.

Answer (score 1):

TexStudio is open source, you can edit the code and change F7 to whatever you want.

Otherwise since you are on Windows, you may try AutoHotKey.

Say you want to use Ctrl+p to open the PDF instead of F7, you will write such AutoHotKey script:

```
#hotif WinActive("ahk_exe texstudio.exe") 
^p::F7
F7:: send "^o"
```

The first line checks if the current window is TexStudio.

The second line maps Ctrl+p to F7.

The third line maps the original F7 to Ctrl+o.

Without the first line, the mappings happen on other programs.

Comment: @hermes `Options` -> `Configure TeXStudio` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Menus` -> `Tools` -> `View`  then change `F7` in third column (`Current Shortcut`).

Comment: @hermes `Options` -> `Configure TeXStudio` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Menus PDF-Viewer` -> `Window` -> `Show` -> `Go to source` then change `Ctrl+'` in third column (`Current Shortcut`)